# MVVM Light WPF binding, lifecycle problems?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm-light

I am fleshing out a Window view for a LOB app. An early version with few XAML elements, but binding the title bar close button to a VM command using EventToCommand on the Closing event works fine. A later version with a few dozen elements, none yet data-bound, fails to bind that button:

```
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=CloseCommand; DataItem=null; target element is 'EventToCommand' (HashCode=42527634); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
```

There are about a dozen other binding errors, referring to Border or Button element properties such as OpacityMask, HeadersVisibility, and the like - again no data binding has been set up yet. In my experience that is not unusual and not a problem?

If I comment out the new XAML elements, the close button binds and executes my CloseCommand.

I'm an MVVM Light 'journeyman', a few successful apps behind me, I *think* I do everything as Laurent suggests in his training and documentation.

Suggestions?

UPDATE:

The only bindings so far, both on the Window element:

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=MainViewModel}"

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
            <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

All the other elements are garden variety LOB layout and widgets with no binding expressions yet.

Comment: What does your binding look like? It sounds like you're changing the `Source` of the binding, but not pointing it to any valid reference.

Comment: Rachel: see update. Thanks for response!

Comment: Do you have an object called `Locator` anywhere in your XAML? And does it have the path `.MainViewModel.CloseCommand`?

Comment: Locator is the name assigned to an instance of MVVM Light's ViewModelLocator, in the Application.Resources of app.xaml. And it has a property MainViewModel being its instance of my VM, which has a CloseCommand property. That's all straight out of the MVVM Light templates. And constant between the working and non-working versions of my window. The non-working one just has more widgets on it. I guess my only vague ideas are that something's haywire in those widgets, or its a timing thing between the window being constructed and the Locator constructing itself and its VM instance.

Comment: yeah wild. I'm adding widgets one by one. At some threshold beyond a few widgets the command stops binding. I guess I have some MVVM Light lifecycle things to learn about?

Comment: Is it a specific widget causing the problem? And does the same problem occur if you just add something like a standard TextBox repeatedly? Also, is this a compile-time error or a runtime error?

Comment: it varies how many of which widget I have, so no I don't think it is a specific widget, especially since I'm not using any I haven't used before. the binding error I show in the question displays in the Output box if you have binding debugging turned on via using the Tools->Options dialog, under Debugging->Output Window - in WPF Trace Settings set Data Binding to All.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a timing issue in the designer then. If it doesn't give you any errors at runtime, I'd just ignore it :)

Comment: the error I include in the question happens at runtime - beyond some threshold # of widgets in the window, the command does not get bound, so it doesn't execute on the Closing event as intended, which is the problem that I'm trying to solve.